# How to read only relevant information from a file and ignore everything else?

Tags: java, io

*Someone please edit my title to make this question more clear.*

It's easier to show using an example:

**Contents of myfile.txt:**

```
10/05/2011: 10
10/05/2011: 45.4
10/05/2011: 12.1
```

I want to read the numbers after the date (10, 45.4, 12.1) using BufferedReader and store in a list. How would I do that? I am using readLine() method right now to read my data, but reads the entire line. I don't want to store date in my list, just the numbers. Is it possible?

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course, although you will have to read the entire line first, once you have done that you can write a simple regular expression to pick what you want in this case numbers.

Alternatively since the numbers are always after ":", this will also work

```
String[] parts = myReadLine.split(":");
String numbers = parts[1];
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of how to do that? Sorry I don't have much experience with Reg Expressions outside of Theoretical Comp Sci course.

Comment: @Blue Pony Inc yes you can use the one provided, it is the easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
String number = br.readLine().split(":")[1];
```

...just add proper error checking....

Comment: Or, if each line starts with a date, one can just take `substring(12)`.

Comment: Yes, just make sure the date part is always 12 characters (01/05/2011: ) and never like 1/5/2011

Answer (score 1):

You could use [subString](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=226) method of the string class to get the required part of the line.

For example.

```
string line = readline()...;

string number = line.substring(12,14);
```

Or you could get the index of ':' and use that index as the first parameter of the substring method.

```
int i = line.indexOf(": ");
string number = line.substring(i, i+2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to edit your post because I do not have high enough privileges, however this process is called parsing.

The algorithm is

```
while(!EOF)
{
    //read until ':'
    //put chars after ':' into a string(or char[]) until you reach a \n
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), is easy. You can especifiy a pattern to read what you need with the [hasNext(String pattern)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28java.lang.String%29) method .